# Why does my rspec test pass by itself but fails when I give a specific test to run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sunspot, webmock

When I run rspec to run all tests, they all pass, but when I give a specific filename, it fails.

```
$ rspec spec/controllers/refinery/books/admin/books_controller_spec.rb


  2) Refinery::Books::Admin::BooksController GET :new responds 200 success
     Failure/Error: login_admin_user #Gives 404
     WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: POST http://localhost:8981/solr/default/update?wt=ruby with body '<?xml ...' with headers {'Content-Type'=>'text/xml'}

       You can stub this request with the following snippet:

       stub_request(:post, "http://localhost:8981/solr/default/update?wt=ruby").
         with(:body => "<?xml ...",
              :headers => {'Content-Type'=>'text/xml'}).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

       registered request stubs:

       stub_request(:post, "http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update?wt=ruby").
         with(:headers => {'Content-Type'=>'text/xml'})

       ============================================================
     # ./lib/rsolr/connection.rb:15:in `execute'
     # (eval):2:in `post'
     # ./spec/support/controller_macros.rb:21:in `login_admin_user'
```

I have it mocked & stubbed already, so why is it failing? The only thing I can see is the existing stub is '/test/' and the request is '/default/'. How did that change?

Ok I ran into this problem again on another spec. Here is the spec: 
https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/1d79d9925f9b79ae5c01

I did find this solr/solr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="false">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
    <core name="default"     instanceDir="." dataDir="default/data"/>
    <core name="development" instanceDir="." dataDir="development/data"/>
    <core name="test"        instanceDir="." dataDir="test/data"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

It's like rspec is running in production environment, even if I explicitely give the environment

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rspec spec/controllers/refinery/books/books_controller_spec.rb
```

I think it is an rspec problem. `rspec -v`: version 2.14.7.

Comment: Hi Chloe, one possibility is that your environment isn't being picked up correctly. If you have a spec_helper class (usually these set the environment name), check that you have 'require spec_helper' at the top of this particular spec. My guess is that SOLR is configured to use /test/ when you are in your 'test' environment, but when you are running this test alone, you are not getting the 'test' configuration

Comment: More specifically, this is the line you are likely to have in your spec_helper that isn't getting pulled in: ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

Comment: Yes I do have `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of the _spec file. The first line of `spec_helper.rb` is `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'`.

Comment: The fact that you have had to add a new line to your stubs that has a different SOLR core name 'test' and also a different port '8983' shows that you are picking up a different config. Suggest that one of the other specs you have is changing your SOLR config somewhere but it is not getting executed when you run this spec alone.

Comment: Wow I didn't see the different port. I searched the entire project directory for 8981 and it only showed up where it was a stub request. I don't know where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `stub_request(:post, "http://localhost:8981/solr/default/update?wt=ruby").to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})` before `login_admin_user` but I don't think that's the root solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably interacting with another test.

Try running the suite in random order

```
rspec spec --order rand
```

and/or try running all the tests for that controller or or controllers.

Comment: I ran that and it still passed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using webmock, which disables all HTTP connections by default.

You can modify you Gemfile to disable auto require as followed:

```
gem "webmock", :require => false
```

And require webmock where you need it (e.g., `require 'webmock/rspec'`). After disabling HTTP connections for certain tests, remember to `WebMock.allow_net_connect!` to allow real http connections for other tests.

Another alternative is to `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(:allow_localhost => true)` to disable external requests while allowing localhost.